# "If" condition Jquery - Validate empty fields

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, conditional-statements

I´m triying to validate by me own two fields. When they are empty I would like to show a message.

The problem is the "if" condition don´t carry out properly and I don´t know why.

This is HTML code:

```
<div id="switchingform">
            <label for="currentsupplier">Who is your current supplier?</label>
            <input type="text" name="currentsupplier" id="currentsupplier"/><br />
            <span class="validateText" id="validateSupplier"><p>Please enter your      current supplier</p></span>

            <label for="postcode">What is your post code?</label>
            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode"/><br />
            <span class="validateText" id="validatePostCode"><p>Please enter your post code</p></span>
</div>
```

And this is JQUERY code:

```
$("#telecomBusNext").click(function(){ 
    if($("#currentsupplier").val().length < 1 || $("#postcode").val().length < 1) { 
        $("#validateSupplier").fadeIn(400);
        $("#validatePostCode").fadeIn(400);
        return false;
    } else if($("#currentsupplier").val().length > 1 || $("#postcode").val().length < 1) {
        $("#validatePostCode").fadeIn(400);
        $("#validateSupplier").fadeOut(400);
        return false;  
    } else if($("#currentsupplier").val().length < 1 || $("#postcode").val().length > 1) {
        $("#validatePostCode").fadeOut(400);
        $("#validateSupplier").fadeIn(400);
        return false;  
    } else {
      $("#validateSupplier").fadeOut(400);
      $("#validatePostCode").fadeOut(400);
    }   
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define 'not working'?

Comment: Change the `||` with `&&` and it should work. You are defining two same conditions in two different conditionals.Your logic is wrong.

Comment: You apparently don't understand the difference between `||` and `&&`. This is a pretty basic misunderstanding for a programmer.

Comment: You check for length less than 1 and length greater than 1. What about length exactly equal to 1?

Comment: Barmar, you are right! I´ve made a stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `||` with `&&` and it should work. You are defining two same conditions in two different conditionals.Your logic is wrong.

```
$("#telecomBusNext").click(function(){ 
    //THIS------------------------------------>   <--ALSO HERE ----------------->
    if($("#currentsupplier").val().length < 1 || $("#postcode").val().length < 1) { 
        $("#validateSupplier").fadeIn(400);
        $("#validatePostCode").fadeIn(400);
        return false;                                //<--AND HERE is the same----->
    } else if($("#currentsupplier").val().length > 1 || $("#postcode").val().length < 1) {
        $("#validatePostCode").fadeIn(400);
        $("#validateSupplier").fadeOut(400);
        return false;
     //AND THIS are the same when using || ----------> 
    } else if($("#currentsupplier").val().length < 1 || $("#postcode").val().length > 1) {
        $("#validatePostCode").fadeOut(400);
        $("#validateSupplier").fadeIn(400);
        return false;  
    } else {
      $("#validateSupplier").fadeOut(400);
      $("#validatePostCode").fadeOut(400);
    }   
});
```

Because both conditionals include `$("#currentsupplier").val().length < 1`  and in the HERE case both include `$("#postcode").val().length < 1`,if one of those is true Jquery does not know which of the two operations marked above should be run.

**EDIT :**

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdP9Q/) i created.

Let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks Stefanos, I made that mistake and you explained to me very good. But now when I change the    ||   with    &&    in wordpress it doesn´t work. Why?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the `#telecomBusNext` element that you click and perhaps i ll make a fiddle to show you how to do it.

Comment: Yes sure. It is a simple submit button. When you click on it, you make a submit and go to the next page.

Here is the code:

<button title="Continue" name="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn" id="telecomBusNext">Continue</button>

The thing is that ampersand simbol doesn´t work properly in Wordpress and I don´t know why. I write $$ (two ampersand) but it becomes &#038;&#038;

Comment: You want both spans to be hidden and if the inputs are empty to show? While when the inputs get a value you want the spans to hide again? Do i understand correctly?

Comment: Stefanos is easy. It´s only to validate two inputs. 
If both are empty show two messages, if one of them is empty show one message and if they aren´t empty go to next page.

Comment: Ok contructing the fiddle now. Wait for it.

Comment: Great!!!! Is exactly that what I´m looking for. Thanks a lot Stefanos! I appreciate so so much your time and your help mate.

Comment: Btw the Fiddle in my answer is different than the fiddle in my comment.The only differene is that the one in my answer EDIT has some animation effect as well in order to replace the fade effects you were using. I am glad i could help:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're using `||` (OR) when you should be using `&&` (AND)`.

But why make it so complicated by checking all the combinations? Check the two fields separately and it will be much easier:

```
$("#telecomBusNext").click(function(){ 
    var supplierValid = $("#currentsupplier").val().length > 0;
    var postcodeValid = $("#postcode").val().length > 0;
    $("#validateSupplier").fadeToggle(!supplierValid);
    $("#validatePostCode").fadeToggle(!postcodeValid);
    return supplierValid && postcodeValid;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but in your way... what happens with the "return false".

Comment: Do you know why in Wordpress the ampersand simbol doesn´t work??
I´m triying to find a solution but I didn´t find nothing about that...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Wordpress.